# how to extract my specific information from each line of output file

Tags: sed, awk, cut

In my output file I have 800,000 rows and 8 fields for 3 samples. I just extract 2 rows here. I want only extract some specific information of each line such as:
chr, position, SNP-ID, Quality, DP, QD, genotypes (./.,0/0,/0/1, or 1/1). I need a script to extract those information and create new file: Could you please advise. Thanks

```
#chr pos SNP-ID Qual Info geno(sample1) geno(sample2) geno(sample3)
chrM 152 rs117135796 7427.14 AC=2;AF=0.333;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=-20.485;DB;DP=702;DS;Dels=0.00;FS=167.659;HaplotypeScore=2.6106;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0.333;MQ=50.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.507;QD=36.77;ReadPosRankSum=12.041 0/0:250,0:237:99:0,701,10320 0/0:250,0:238:99:0,713,10507 1/1:0,202:192:99:7465,572,0
chr10 5874 rs118203891 33.13 AC=1;AF=0.167;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=1.454;DB;DP=657;DS;Dels=0.00;FS=124.424;HaplotypeScore=5.1214;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.167;MQ=45.31;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=2.462;QD=0.15;ReadPosRankSum=-8.096 0/1:204,24:206:64:64,0,6345 0/0:203,0:193:99:0,473,6944 0/0:226,0:215:99:0,524,6448
```

Comment: You need to show us what you want the output to look like. Don't make us guess.

Comment: As I explained in the box, I need to extract only chr, pos, snp, quality, DP, QD and genotpes of 3 samples. for example for row1, I like to have like this: chrM 152 rs117135796 7427.14 DP=702 QD=36.77 0/0 0/0 1/1

Comment: Thanks glenn for the script. In fact I have a file with more than 800,000 rows. Which part of the script needs to be change to be apply for my file. (this example only had 2 rows)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk -f ext.awk data.txt > summary.txt
```

where `data.txt` is your input data file, and `ext.awk` is:

```
NR>1 {
    match($5,/(DP=[^;]+);/,a)
    DP=a[1]
    match($5,/(QD=[^;]+);/,a)
    QD=a[1]
    match($6,/^([^:]+\/[^:]+):/,a)
    gt1=a[1]
    match($7,/^([^:]+\/[^:]+):/,a)
    gt2=a[1]
    match($8,/^([^:]+\/[^:]+):/,a)
    gt3=a[1]
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,DP,QD,gt1,gt2,gt3
}
```

### Update

Assuming the genotypes are given by the 3 first characters of each field (from $6 to $NF) you could try the following:

```
NR>1 {
    match($5,/(DP=[^;]+);/,a)
    DP=a[1]
    match($5,/(MQ=[^;]+);/,a)
    MQ=a[1]
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s ", $1,$2,$3,$4,DP,MQ
    for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s", substr($i,1,3)
        if (i<NF) printf " "
        else printf "\n"
    }
}
```

### Update

If you want to:

- if DP<10 or MQ<50 then delete that line;
- convert genotypes as follows: (NA, 0, 1, 2)
- convert  ./.  to "NA",
- convert  0/0  to "0"
- convert  0/1  to "1"
- convert  1/1  to "2"

then you can try:

```
BEGIN {
    geno["./."]="NA"
    geno["0/0"]="0"
    geno["0/1"]="1"
    geno["1/1"]="2"
}
NR>1 {
    match($5,/(DP=[^;]+);/,a)
    DP=a[1]
    match(DP,/=(.*)$/,a)
    dpv=a[1]
    match($5,/(MQ=[^;]+);/,a)
    MQ=a[1]
    match(MQ,/=(.*)$/,a)
    mqv=a[1]
    if (dpv<10 || mqv<50) next
    else {
        printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s ", $1,$2,$3,$4,DP,MQ
        for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) {
            type=substr($i,1,3)
            printf "%s", geno[type]
            if (i<NF) printf " "
            else printf "\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hakon, Thanks for the script. It works perfect. But as I said in my question I have 4 class of genotypes(./., 0/0/, 0/1, 1/1). but your program only read and write 3 class of genotype (0/0,0/1,1/1). how I can fix this issue. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: I think it reads `./.` also. I tested it now and replaced `0/0` in your last row with `./.`, and it printed the value correctly..

Comment: Hi Hakon,This is two rows of my file. When I used your script.awk is not extract information correctly. I have 51 columns and almost 1.5 million rows. I changed your script to read all 51 columns but as can see some of field og genotype are different. How to fix this problem.

Comment: I am not able to send you even one row because of limitation of this block size.

Comment: but I can send the example file if you send me your email. my email is mahyarhey@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

Perl gives a nice terse program:

```
perl -ane '
    BEGIN {$, = " "}
    @fields = @F[0..3];
    push @fields, $1, $2 if $F[4] =~ /(DP=.+?);.*(QD=.+?);/;
    push @fields, (split /:/)[0] for @F[5,6,7];
    print @fields, "\n";
' <<END
chrM 152 rs117135796 7427.14 AC=2;AF=0.333;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=-20.485;DB;DP=702;DS;Dels=0.00;FS=167.659;HaplotypeScore=2.6106;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0.333;MQ=50.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=-1.507;QD=36.77;ReadPosRankSum=12.041 0/0:250,0:237:99:0,701,10320 0/0:250,0:238:99:0,713,10507 1/1:0,202:192:99:7465,572,0
chr10 5874 rs118203891 33.13 AC=1;AF=0.167;AN=6;BaseQRankSum=1.454;DB;DP=657;DS;Dels=0.00;FS=124.424;HaplotypeScore=5.1214;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.167;MQ=45.31;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=2.462;QD=0.15;ReadPosRankSum=-8.096 0/1:204,24:206:64:64,0,6345 0/0:203,0:193:99:0,473,6944 0/0:226,0:215:99:0,524,6448
END
```

```
chrM 152 rs117135796 7427.14 DP=702 QD=36.77 0/0 0/0 1/1 
chr10 5874 rs118203891 33.13 DP=657 QD=0.15 0/1 0/0 0/0
```